# Determine a Class’s Type from a string and use that as the TVal in a SortedList

Tags: c#, .net, generics

As a preamble, I’m trying to use to following with a number of classes which map database tables to C# for some internal development tools.  What I am attempting to do is use a string to specify a class type, then use that class’s type as the TVal in a sorted list, and finally instantiate the class using Activator and add it to the list.

Assuming this is possible, I think my main issue is not knowing the proper syntax of how to use ‘classType’ in `SortedList` and `Activator` lines.

The following doesn’t work, however hopefully it will give a clear idea what I am trying to accomplish.

```
string className = "ClassName";
System.Type classType = Type.GetType(className);
SortedList<int,classType> rcdsList = new SortedList<int,classType>();
rcdsList.Add(key,(classType)Activator.CreateInstance(classType , paramArray));
```

Edit: This is what I ended up figuring for a solution out since I posted the original question.  Basically it's setting up the SortedList using the base class and then casting the activator result.

```
string tableClassName = "Table_" + tableNames[i];
System.Type targetType = Type.GetType("DbUtilities." + tableClassName);

SortedList<int, DbUtilities.DbObjectTableBase> rcdsList = new SortedList<int, DbUtilities.DbObjectTableBase>();

while (!rcd.EOF)
{
    object[] paramArray = new object[rcd.Fields.Count];

    for (int j = 0; j < rcd.Fields.Count; j++)
    {
        paramArray[j] = rcd.Fields[j].Value;
    }

    DbUtilities.DbObjectTableBase obj = (DbUtilities.DbObjectTableBase)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(targetType.AssemblyQualifiedName), paramArray);

    rcdsList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rcd.Fields[0].Value), obj);
    rcd.MoveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how generics work.  Generics are a *compile time* construct, while you're trying to determine the type at *run-time*.  Since you're going to have to cast or use reflection anyways why not just use a `SortedList<int, object>` or `SortedList<int, {some other base class}>`?

Comment: Since asking, that's what I ended up figuring out.  I have a base class I can use for the SortedList TVal and then use Type.GetType() to cast the Activator.  I'll update my original post with what ended up working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Helper {
  public static SortedList<int,T> SetupList<T>(int key, object[] paramArray) {
    var rcdsList = new SortedList<int,T>();
    rcdsList.Add(key, (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), paramArray));
  } 
}
```

Then to call your method (this is calling it passing in a key of 1 and no constructor args)

```
MethodInfo mi=typeof(Helper).GetMethod("SetupList");
    mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType(className)); 
object result = mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1, new object[0]});
```

You could make a similar method that just adds an item to an existing item and then call it in the same way